# Split array into s number of subsets with uniq elements

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Given an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and number s which represents the `splits` how can I generate the below sequence (hope I covered all the combinations for s=3).

The array it's sorted and each subset `s` must contain at least 1 element.

```
s = 2
{1} {2, 3, 4, 5}
{1, 2} {3, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 4}, { 5 }
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

s = 3
{1}, {2}, {3, 4, 5}
{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}
{1}, {2, 3, 4}, {5}
{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}
{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5}
{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}
{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5}
```

I can solve this problem when `s=2` but have no idea what to do when `s>2`.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem that you describe as a **"m out of N Code"** or [constant weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-weight_code) code...

N is the lenght of the word (in your case 5 -1 = 4)
m is the weight or how many splits you want to do (- s in your case)

Word               : 1-+-2-+-3-+-4-+-5
split position     :   1   2   3   4

Then you can say your splits is a boolean array (when you want to do a split the bit in the split position array is true or 1)

So you have a code where you have four (N-1) possible bits where always two (s) have to be true. 
 ie N=4 and s=2.

```
[0011],
[0101],
[1001], etc.
```

As in this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_bound#2) said there is no analytical way to define the number of possibilities for any arbitary combination. But for small numbers you can just use a brute force method with a simple program. Written in python, its not the most pythonic but easyier to read.

**Code:**

```
def check(m,N):
    candidates = range(0, 2**(N-1))
    valid_candidates = []
    for candidate in candidates:
        binary_representation = [int(x) for x in list(('{:0%sb}' % (N-1)).format(candidate))]
        if sum(binary_representation) == m:
            #found candidate
            print(binary_representation)
            valid_candidates.append(binary_representation)
    return valid_candidates


if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 5
    s = 2
    print("Number of valid combinations with N=%s and s=%s is: %s " %(N, s, len(check(s, N))))
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
Number of valid combinations with N=5 and s=2 is: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is with recursion. Something like this (JavaScript code):

```js
function f(arr,k){
  if (k === 1)
    return [[arr]];
      
  var result = [];

  for (var i=1; i<=arr.length-k+1; i++){
    var head = arr.slice(0,i),
        tail = arr.slice(i),
        rest = f(tail,k - 1);

    rest.map(x => result.push([head].concat(x)));
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,2,3,4,5],3)));
```